# How to Resolve Promise for Another Promise?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, twitter, request, promise

The title is confusing, sorry.

I need to look at the contents of a promise for a subsequent promise.

See my previous thread for context: [How to sequentially handle asynchronous results from API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38083380/how-to-sequentially-handle-asynchronous-results-from-api/38083777#38083777)

I have working code below, and I annotated my problem:

```
    var promises = [];

    while (count) {
        var promise = rp(options);
        promises.push(promise);
        // BEFORE NEXT PROMISE, I NEED TO GET ID OF AN ELEMENT IN THIS PROMISE'S DATA
        // AND THEN CHANGE 'OPTIONS' 
    }

    Promise.all(promises).then(values => {
        for (var i = 0; i < values; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
                results.push(values[i][j].text);
            }
        }
        return res.json(results);
    }, function(reason) {
        trace(reason);
        return res.send('Error');
    });
```

Comment: `Accepting an answer is important as it both rewards posters for solving your problem and informs others that your issue is resolved.`  i checked your thread for context, you haven't done anything with it

Comment: I was still in the process of solving the problem and just had a quick follow up question. Thanks for reminding me to accept an answer though. @Oxi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a perfect example of how promises can be chained, because the result of `then` is a new promise.

```
while (count) {
    var promise = rp(options);
    promises.push(promise.then(function(result) {
        result.options = modify(result.options);  // as needed
        return result.options;
    });
}
```

In this way, each promise given to Promise.all can be preprocessed.

Answer (score 0):

If one promise depends upon another (e.g. it can't be executed until the prior one has finished and provided some data), then you need to chain your promises.  There is no "reaching into a promise to get some data".  If you want its result, you wait for it with `.then()`.

```
rp(options).then(function(data) {
    // only here is the data from the first promise available 
    // that you can then launch the next promise operation using it
});
```

If you're trying to do this sequence `count` times (which is what your code implies), then you can create a wrapper function and call itself from the completion of each promise until the count is reached.

```
function run(iterations) {
     var count = 0;
     var options = {...};   // set up first options
     var results = [];      // accumulate results here

     function next() {
          return rp(options).then(function(data) {
              ++count;
              if (count < iterations) {
                  // add anything to the results array here
                  // modify options here for the next run
                  // do next iteration
                  return next();
              } else {
                  // done with iterations
                  // return any accumulated results here to become
                  // the final resolved value of the original promise
              }
          });
     }
     return next();
}

// sample usage
run(10).then(function(results) {
      // process results here
}, function(err) {
      // process error here
});
```

Comment: @MelvinLu - Did this solve your problem or answer your question?